# cannot require rubygems, perhaps because of multiple ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I cannot require rubygems in my ruby files: (although I can require other modules - such as rexml/document)

my `01.rb` file:

```
require "rubygems"
```

When execute `ruby 01.rb`, I got:

```
01.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from 01.rb:1
```

However this is the output of some commands on my system:
***My ruby version (I think I have multiples, which causes the problem, Right? - should I remove all and re-install from scratch?)***

```
mhewedy@compu10:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

mhewedy@compu10:~$ which -a ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

mhewedy@compu10:~$ ls -lt /usr/bin/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 11 07:28 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby

mhewedy@compu10:~$ ls -lt /etc/alternatives/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Sep 27 10:00 /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.8

mhewedy@compu10:~$ ls /usr/bin/ruby*
/usr/bin/ruby  /usr/bin/ruby1.8  /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1  /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3
```

**And here's my gem env**

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/mhewedy/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

**I fix this** by making my `system-wide ruby` version (the one results from `which ruby`, which is `/usr/bin/ruby`) to point to the same one in the output of `gen env` - which is `1.9.1`.

I did this -on my ubuntu box- using:

`sudo update-alternatives --config ruby`

then chosen version that matches the one in output of `gem env`